# I want to put a while loop into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array where under `"images"` I want to loop 4 rows from my database. It means I am trying to put a loop into an array. Help me.

```
$sql_album = "SELECT * FROM albums";
$res_album = mysql_query($sql_album) or die(mysql_error());

$albums = array();

while ($row_album = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_album)) {
    $albums[$row_album['title']] = array(
        "description" => $row_album['description'], 
        "date" => $row_album['date'], 
        "images" => array(
            //i want to insert a loop here shown down
        )
    );
}
```

This is the loop i want to insert where i wrote the comment in the upper script:

```
$sql_thumb = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album_id = '".$row_album['id']."' LIMIT 0, 4";
$res_thumb = mysql_query($sql_thumb) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row_thumb = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_thumb)) {
    echo $row_thumb['thumb_url'];
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, php not allow you to do this.

Comment: Why don't you run the loop first, and then insert the results into the "images" element? That should work. Don't make your code messy with zillion nested things.

Comment: @srain Yeah, but there must be a way. For example, into the "images" to create an array and then make a loop at the end of the script

Comment: This is a dumb solution. See JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start here...

```
include('../path/to/mysqli/connection/statements');

$query = "
SELECT a.id
     , a.title
     , a.description
     , a.date
     , p.thumb_url
  FROM albums a
  LEFT
  JOIN photos p
    ON p.album_id = a.id
 ORDER
    BY a.id;
";

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db,$query);
```

Comment: Works, but how should i insert the result of the query into the "images" element?

Comment: Well, roughly, while($current_album == $row_album['title']){$image[] = $row['image'];} But this is standard stuff - and there are many out there better equipped to advise on constructing loops in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Sadly PHP does not allow this kind of usage. You could however do something like this

```
$sql_album = "SELECT * FROM albums";
$res_album = mysql_query($sql_album) or die(mysql_error());

$albums = array();

while ($row_album = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_album)) {
    $albums[$row_album['title']] = array(
        "description" => $row_album['description'], 
        "date" => $row_album['date'], 
        "images" => array()
    );

    $sql_thumb = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album_id = '".$row_album['id']."' LIMIT 0, 4";
    $res_thumb = mysql_query($sql_thumb) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row_thumb = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_thumb)) {
        $albums[$row_album['title']]["images"][] = row_thumb['thumb_url'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know. I'm just hoping to find another way to do it.

Comment: Well there are plenty of ways to achive this effect. You need to be a bit more specific of what you want.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "sad". Writing code inside an array constructor is a feature i've only ever seen in Python and even there it often makes code much harder to read.